# Помощь с умным фильтром Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Я хочу чтобы тайтл страницы определялся из шаблона META_TITLE в настройках SEO. Умный фильтр у меня работает так: по нажатию на значение фильтра происходит обновление страницы, в class.php умного фильтра происходит обработка шаблона, код показан ниже, И всё вроде бы ок, я получаю обработанный шаблон, но в тайтле показывается необработанный шаблон. Может что-то перекрывать? Просто на 100 процентов уверен, что данные обработались нормально (проверил через вывод перед SetPageProperty). С битрикс плохо знаком, делал по аналогии с другим сайтом, так как поставлена задача перенести фильтр.

```
foreach ($this->arResult['SET_FILTERS'] as $key => $item) {
            $this->arResult['SET_FILTERS'][$key] = implode(' и ', $item);

        }
        $ipropValues = new \Bitrix\Iblock\InheritedProperty\SectionValues(26, $this->arResult['SECTION']['ID']);
        $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"] = $ipropValues->getValues();
     
        // Открываем файл в нужном нам режиме. Нам же, нужно его создать и что то записать.

        // \[(.+)?%.+%(.+)?]
        global $APPLICATION;
        // записываем данные в открытый файл
        foreach ($this->arResult['SET_FILTERS'] as $key => $item) {
            $this->arResult['SET_FILTERS']["%rs_$key%"] = $item;
            unset($this->arResult['SET_FILTERS'][$key]);
        }

        $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"] = str_replace(array_keys($this->arResult['SET_FILTERS']), array_values($this->arResult['SET_FILTERS']), $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]);

        foreach ($this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"] as &$row) {
            $temp = explode('^', $row);
            if (count($temp) > 1) {
                foreach ($temp as $key => $item) {
                    /* Если в группе осталась не замененная переменна, то удаляем всю группу */
                    $pos = strpos($item, '%rs_');
                    // $item = trim($item);
                    if ($pos !== false) {
                        unset($temp[$key]);
                    } 
                    // if ($item == '') {
                    //  unset($temp[$key]);
                    // }
                }
                $row = implode('', $temp);
            }
            // $row = preg_replace('#\s*\%.+\%\s*#U', '', $row);
        }
        
        
        // $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"] = str_replace(['[', ']'], '', preg_replace('#\[.*?%.*?%.*?\]#g', '', $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]));
        $APPLICATION->IPROPERTY_VALUES = $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"];

        // $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]['SECTION_META_TITLE'];
        $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $this->arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]['SECTION_META_TITLE']);
        $APPLICATION->SetTitle($this->arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['SECTION_PAGE_TITLE'], $this->arResult['IPROPERTY_VALUES']['SECTION_PAGE_TITLE']);
```

Comment: Функция $APPLICATION->SetTitle() может вызываться несколькими компонентами. В результате заголовок определяется последним вызовом. Вероятно, на странице есть другие компоненты, которые переопределяют заголовок. Нужно в их настройках отключить эту опцию.